# putting .size() into new column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am very new to python (and to stack overflow!) so hopefully this makes sense!

I have a dataframe which contains years and names (amongst otherthings however this is all I am interested in working with). 
I have done `df = df.groupby(['year', 'name']).size()` to get the amount of times each names appears in each year.

it returns something similar to this:

```
 year   name
 2001   nameone      2
 2001   nametwo      3
 2002   nameone      1
 2002   nametwo      5
```

what I'm trying to do is put the size data in to a new column called 'count'.
(eventually what I am intending to do with this is plot it on graphs)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Here is the raw code (I have condensed it a bit for convenience) :

```
hso_df = pd.read_csv('HibernationSurveyObservationsCleaned.csv')

hso_df[["startDate", "endDate", "commonName"]] 

year_df = hso_df
year_df['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(hso_df['startDate'] )
year_df['year'] = year_df['startDate'].dt.year

year_df = year_df[["year", "commonName"]].sort_values('year') 

year_df = year_df.groupby(['year', 'commonName']).size()
```

[here is an image of the first 3 rows of the data displayed with .head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxnzg.jpg)

The only columns that are of interest from this data are the commonName and the year (I have taken this from startDate)

Comment: you need to post the data also

Comment: The data is a .csv file, I cannot upload that can I?

Comment: post a link to the file

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tpBWdwxsIMg8f1aljZ_U0Fw_A7mRXqEDNubmA8H80zo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK can you try this: year_df= year_df.reset_index()` after your last line and then do `hso_df.merge(year_df).rename(columns={0:'count'})`

Comment: That's it! Thank you for taking your time to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want `transform` to add the result of the groupby with its index aligned to the original df:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['year', 'name']).transform('size')
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your requirements, I suggest calling `reset_index` on the `groupby` result and then merging this back to your main df:

```
year_df= year_df.reset_index()
hso_df.merge(year_df).rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I have tried using transform but cannot successfully get it working, I am just getting errors.

Comment: Hmm, the issue here could be that you have 2 columns in the index so maybe what would work would be something like `df['count'] = df.merge(df,df.groupby(['year', 'name']).size().reset_index())`

Comment: On running the transform statement I get the error "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1". When running the one you just suggested I get the error "TypeError: Could not compare ['left'] with block values" - I'm not entirely sure what either of those mean!

Comment: Can you post raw code and data to reproduce your df and I'll have a look

Comment: Okay, I have edited the original question with more detail. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help.